# A Core data Sort on Relationship's Attribute in ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, local-database

I'm having 2 entities `CDChatConversation` and `CDMessage`. `CDConversation` having `to many` relationship with messages.
I want to fetch all conversation with sorting of lastMessage's datetime attribute which is kind of `Date`.

Currently I'm using following predicate and FetchRequest but I think this will take more time when I'm having more data.

```
func getChatConversationSorted() throws -> [CDChatConversation] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDMessage> = CDMessage.fetchRequest()
    let timePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateTime = conversation.messages.@max.dateTime")
    fetchRequest.predicate = timePredicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(CDMessage.dateTime), ascending: false)]
    let fetchedMessages = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let fetchedConversations = fetchedMessages.compactMap({$0.conversation})
    return fetchedConversations
}
```

How can I directly predicate on `CDChatConversation`?

Comment: One option could be to have a modification date property in CDChatConversation that gets updated every time the conversation is updated and sort on that.

Comment: How much data is "more"? Are you going to have millions of records?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That would be not feasible

Comment: @TomHarrington Not really, but may be thousands of.